# Custom plugin init action causing general slowness

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, actions

I'm developing a custom plugin which connects to salesforce and needs to check that the connection hasn't expired on each page refresh. If it does expire, it reconnects etc.

So I am doing this on an init action, but I've noticed a very significant performance hit doing it this way. Particularly loading images from the media library. My understanding now is that init fires with every request, so on a page with 20 images, it will fire at least 20 times??? Is this correct?

So obviously init isn't the best for this purpose, what should I be using?

Kevin

Comment: Init fires with every request, even `admin-ajax.php` (which wp admin checks regularly for auth verification). Such remote requests should make the site slow and it would be better to process them via AJAX.

Comment: Images are physical files, WordPress isn't loaded to serve requests for physical files.

Comment: So I'm a bit confused by what constitutes a 'request' then, I put a trivial counter in my init script which just increments a $_SESSION variable and by the time I get to the foot of my page my counter is on 7. So init is firing 7 times on 1 page load. I assumed this was because I am calling wp_get_attachment_src a few times - but maybe not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your function to fire only once, you can use other hooks.

`wp_head` might be useful in your situation since it is fired before the rest of the template is rendered.

`template_redirect` is also fired before rendering the template.

If the sequence doesn't matter to you, you can fire it at last using `wp_footer` or `get_footer` hook.

Comment: Thanks @jack, I used 'wp' and that seemed to do the trick to - are there any things I should be aware of using that do you think?

Comment: This hook runs right after `WP class`, so in some situations it might be too early to do whatever you are trying to do. If it's working fine for you, then no further action is required.